# select all duplicates on two different column combinations based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe that looks like follows :

```
     A_key     t_num    r_num  o_st 
292  A1         16       TS      Q
812  A1         16       TS      Q
173  A5         15       TT      Q
955  A7         19       TQ      Q
804  A7         17       TR      Q
49   A7         18       TQ      Q
668  A1         28       None    P 
788  A4         88       None    P 
693  A7         17       TS      Q
781  A1         22       None    P
```

I want to select all distinct rows for a unique combination of A_key and t_num for  o_st = 'P' and all distinct rows for a unique combination of A_key and r_num for o_st = 'Q' into a new dataframe. Appreciate any responses

Expected df looks like the following

```
   A_key     t_num    r_num  o_st 
292  A1         16       TS      Q
173  A5         15       TT      Q
955  A7         19       TQ      Q
804  A7         17       TR      Q
668  A1         28       None    P 
788  A4         88       None    P 
693  A7         17       TS      Q
781  A1         22       None    P
```

Comment: Do you care about order being maintained in the final DataFrame?

Comment: @user3483203 - Nope, as long as I have all the data order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `where` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df['key'] = df['t_num'].where(df['o_st'].eq('P'), df['r_num'])

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A_key', 'key']).drop('key', 1)
```

```
    A_key  t_num r_num o_st
292    A1     16    TS    Q
173    A5     15    TT    Q
955    A7     19    TQ    Q
804    A7     17    TR    Q
668    A1     28  None    P
788    A4     88  None    P
693    A7     17    TS    Q
781    A1     22  None    P
```

---

You have two distinct subsets that you want to check for uniqueness depending on the value of the third column.  Instead of calling `drop_duplicates` twice, I create a mask that contains the correct subset value before calling `drop_duplicates` a single time.